# Echo out information from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, html, parsing

I have a table like this in mysql called links_tbl which has 5 rows of data

```
ID,  LINKurl      LINKname

1   google.com     GOOGLE
2
3
4
5
```

By using php i want to echo out the 5 lines onto a html page as a link something like this:

```
echo "<li> <a href=$linkurl></a>$LINKname</li>"
```

What I am having problem with this is that I cannot understand how to get all the LINKurl and LINKname rows from the table to echo them out in the list.

Can anyboby help me out with the coding?

Comment: This is PHP/MySQL 101. You should read a tutorial before asking questions here, but take a look at the example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
//Database Settings
$host = "sql.yourserver.com";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$dbnm = "database_name";

//Connect to Database
$conn = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $pass);
if ($conn) {
$db= mysql_select_db ($dbnm);
if (!$db) {
    die ("Database Not Found"); 
}
} else {
    notify("Fatal Error. Can not connect to Database", ""); 
}

//Form Query
$query =  "SELECT * FROM `links_tbl`";

//Fetch Results
$data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//Start UL
echo "<ul>\n"

//Loop through results
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
      //echo the list item
      echo "<li><a href=".$info['LINKurl'].">".$info['LINKname']."</a></li>\n";  
 }

//End UL
echo "</ul>\n"
```

Keep in mind you need to close the `<a>` tag AFTER you output the name.

Comment: The Order By keyword. I'd have to see the table to be more specific. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: what is the table name and how is it arranged?

Comment: the table name is CLICKS, the table consists of 4 columns, ID, USERID, LINKID and COUNT:::::And the table where i store links is called LINKS, and columns are , ID, LINKurl and LINKname

Comment: It would be something like i added above, cant write code in comments

Comment: Oh, there's probably an easier way to do this in php. Are the LINKID in clicks and the ID in Links the same thing?

Comment: YA the linkid is same in each table

Comment: I can't find the example code I used to have, but read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php Long story short, turn both into arrays, sort the links array by the count array

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDO to do the query:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT LINKurl, LINKname FROM [YOUR TABLE]");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");

foreach($sth->fetchAll()as $result)
{
     echo "<li><a href=\"{$result[0]}\">{$result[1]}</a></li>"
}
```

The result fetched will have the fields

Comment: As @EPICWebDesign pointed out, the closing `</a>` tag should be after the link text. And the value for `href` should be enclosed in quotes. I fixed it for you...hope you don't mind.

Comment: Other thing would be reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

you can di like this

```
$query = "select * from 'yourtbale'";

$result = mysql_query('yourdb',$query);
```

in your view file, loop around your result

```
foreach($result as $value){
     <a href='$value['linkurl']'>$value['linkname']</a>
}
```

Comment: Nope. You didn't fetch the row. You're example will try to loop through a mysql resource, not the resulting rows from the query. And you don't have an `echo` statement. This will get a couple syntax errors.

Comment: yup ur ight mate, it should be `foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc($result) as £value)`